# Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in BIRT Report

Tags: java, weblogic, birt

This is the error I get when I run my birt report in weblogic server started by eclipse. Its working fine in dev environment(local). when i deployed in testing server, I am getting this error. Please any one help me how to fix this issue. Please find the below i have posted error details:

```
## org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2371)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:277)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)##

## Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)##
```

Comment: how much data do you fetch with your report? is there any code on some event when running report?

Comment: I can fetch min 20 to 300 data. Its working fine in local machine. I am getting problem in when i deployed in testing server.I can pass the dateRange from my jsp to birt report file.

Comment: What are your weblogic settings in `setDomainEnv.sh`. You may simply need to bump up your default `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` value for `WLS_MEM_ARGS`.

Comment: if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (
 set WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
 set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms128m -Xmx640m
) else (
 set WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
 set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms128m -Xmx640m
)

Comment: Defaults values in setDomainEnv.sh

Comment: What I would do is to narrow down the issue by checking what is the structure using the most space.

Some check-in questions: 
1. Do you use any local variables of type array or map?
2. Do you have any huge data sets used? You can check data set size by creating new label displaying `Total.count()`
3. For which report parameters does the issue happen and for which it does not? This might help you to narrow down what data causes the issue.

Comment: You may have a look at this: [10 points about Java Heap Space or Java Heap Memory](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html)

Comment: If you're using Oracle JDBC and BIRT 4.3 or newer, you may be hitting a BIRT bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407299

Answer (score 4):

This [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407299) seems to exist since BIRT 4.2.2 and still persists in BIRT 4.4.2.

I succesfully fixed this behaviour by setting the `Row Fetch Size` to `10` in the advanced property tab of the DataSet.

[image]

The Row Fetch Size in the DataSet details dialog seems to be ignored as a matter of facts and a default value of `10000` is being used instead, which turns even smaller queries into memory eaters.

The bug seems to affect Oracle JDBC drivers particularly and especially when a lot of bigger VARCHAR columns are being fetched, even with only a few rows.

Comment: Thanks, I run into this problem recently, and your answer fixed my problem. However it would be nice if they had already fixed this bug...

Answer (score 0):

The “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error will be triggered when you try to add more data into the heap space area in memory, but the size of this data is larger than the JVM can accommodate in the Java heap space.

You can increase the heap size this Java process is allowed to use by specifying (or increasing if present) the following in your JVM startup parameters:

```
-Xmx1024m
```